# Can Cross Site Scripting Filter be disabled from aspx page or using web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I want to turn OFF Internet Explorer cross site scripting xss filter for my website. Is it possible to do so via web.config or on the aspx webpage? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control (change) browser settings from within server application, whatever they are. So, no, it's not possible.

Explain what you're trying to achieve; maybe there's another solution to that.

Comment: Can add HTTP headers from web.config or could configure through IIS

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can disable the XSS filter for your site.  Simply send the following header:

```
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565647(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

We can configure HTTP headers through web.config or via IIS

http://insiderattack.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/configuring-secure-iis-response-headers.html